# Testacular in Windows 64-bit cannot start browser

Tags: node.js, windows-8, 64-bit, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm trying to test an AngularJS app with Testacular in Windows 8 64-bit.

When I run the "yeoman test" or "testacular start" command I get an error saying; "The system cannot find the path specified":

```
C:\Users\me\Dropbox\GitHub\Studentportalen\studentportalen>yeoman test

Running "test" task
info: Testacular server started at http://localhost:8080/
info (launcher): Starting browser PhantomJS
warn (watcher): Pattern "C:/Users/me/Dropbox/GitHub/Studentportalen/st
udentportalen/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
error (launcher): Cannot start PhantomJS
    CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the path specified.

info (launcher): Trying to start PhantomJS again.
error (launcher): Cannot start PhantomJS
    CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the path specified.

info (launcher): Trying to start PhantomJS again.
error (launcher): Cannot start PhantomJS
    CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the path specified.

info: Disconnecting all browsers
<WARN> Command failed:  Use --force to continue. </WARN>

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've tried setting Testacular to use Chrome instead of PhantomJS, but get the same error. So PhantomJS is not the problem.

I've heard it happens because Node.js doesn't like 64-bit Windows (?).
A workaround could be to set up a 32-bit VM for testing, but that is obviously not optimal.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across this problem too. I found that to run the Chrome version I had to create a system variable called "CHROME_BIN" pointing at my chrome.exe file. So I just tried creating a "PHANTOMJS_BIN" variable that pointed to my phantom.cmd file and "hey presto" it worked :)

Comment: This didnt help me on Windows 7 (64bit). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526013/testacular-doesnt-launch-chrome-browser

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, testacular/Node.js work fine in 64-bit Windows. The problem is that the launch configuration files for most browsers use the 'ProgramFiles' environment variable in the browser's file path. On 64-bit Windows, this points to 'Program Files' instead of 'Program Files (x86)' where most browsers are installed.

There are two solutions:

- as johngeorgewright suggests, use [BROWSER]_BIN environment variables that point to the correct locations: [Testacular Browser Configuration](http://testacular.github.com/0.6.0/config/browsers.html)
- Change the launch configuration files. These plain JS files are located in the sub-directory 'lib\launchers' of the testacular installation.